# Flex 4 Scrollbar Skin does not resize

Tags: apache-flex, scrollbar, skinning

I'm working on a Flex 4 application and I started customizing the interface with skins to give a whole new look.

So, I've created two scrollbar skins in Flash Catalyst (one horizontal, one vertical).

Its working great when I test the application through Catalyst so I took it and imported it on Flash Builder, copied the components and defined the new skins in my css file for the HScrollbar and VScrollbar.

The skin is working, all the buttons are ok. But, the scrollbar isnt resizing for some reason. It remains in the same height I've designed it to be regardless of the content it is bound to.

It scrolls the content in all the ways it should be but it doesnt resize and the thumb isnt getting all the way down.

Also I've noticed the following.

I have a custom component acting as a list. It extends Group and contains a Scroller. So at one place of the application the Scrollthumb is getting lower than on another place where the same custom list is used.

I also have to mention that this scroller works perfectly without a custom skin.

Anyone else having similar problems?

Comment: Yeah; I have the same problems, and I can't find anywhere that addresses this specific issue. Scrollbar skins are supposed to auto-resize unless you have the individual components (track, thumb, etc) set to specific heights/widths (as opposed to giving them minHeight/minWidth), but I haven't been able to make it work no matter what I do.

Have you gotten this figured out yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your graphic elements are defined as every single part of the scrollbar (top arrow, bottom arrow, track, etc...): in this case you should check that the elements dimensions are not fixed... they should be in % to be able to change the dimensions based on the container.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I know you posted this a while ago but I have been scouring the internet for days looking for why the scrollbar's thumb wasn't scaling like the default scrollbar.

There are a couple things to check, first is there a set height on your thumb's skin?

If not, and this is what I was overlooking, go to your scroller skin and at the point where you add the vertical and horizontal scrollbar set the "fixedThumbSize" property to false.